# Showing Hierarchical Node Structure of DOM with FireBug

Tags: firefox, dom, firebug

I am using FireFox 20.0 and am using FireBug to debug my JavaScript code.  When I clicked on the DOM tag, it would shows the hieracrchical node structure with fields like children, childNodes, nodeValue, etc.  I accidentally closed the tab and when I brought it back I was unable to get this structure with FireBug.  It had several options like "Show User-defined Properties", "Show User-defined Functions", "Show DOM Properties", "Show DOM Functions", etc but none of these options show the structure that I had before with children, childNodes, nodeValue, etc.

How do I get the old structure back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to fix the problem is to click on the FireBug option, choose Options and then "Reset All Firebug Options".   That checks the following under DOM.
- Show User-defined Properties
- Show User-defined Functions
- Show DOM properties
- Show Enumerable Properties Only

I can still get what I want by unchecking "Show User-defined Functions".